# Burninate request: [colon], [plus], etc

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Going through the review queue on Stack Overflow, I found a bunch of tags that just look like they're for individual ASCII characters or random words. I can't imagine them being useful for searching or indexing. Some samples:

- [hyphen](/questions/tagged/hyphen)
- [plus](/questions/tagged/plus)
- [minus](/questions/tagged/minus)
- [colon](/questions/tagged/colon)

Is there any reason to keep any of these tags? (In retrospect, I shouldn't have approved some of these edits...)

Comment: [tag:having] is an SQL tag. Other than that, these I agree are silly.

Comment: [tag:colon] is just horrible.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `having` was a specific keyword. I've removed it from the list.

Comment: Keep in mind that a *lot* of search engines have a very hard time looking for punctuation.  These tags are one way -- not a good way, just one way -- to help people find things related to punctuation in syntax.  Be careful about blindly nuking them, there might be a legitimate case for them to exist.  *Most* cases will be abusive and un-needed, but not all.

Comment: @Charles: that's why you place the full name in the title or the body text - no need for tags.

Comment: What if I'm having colon overflow problems? Where would I go?

Comment: @Emrakul: To the doctor. ;-)